# Theorem related to Triangle.

Tags: geometry

Prove that in triangle $ABC$ if angle bisectors drawn from $B$ and $C$ are congruent then $AB=AC$.

Answer (score 3):

This is the Steiner-Lehmus Theorem. See, e.g., [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner–Lehmus_theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner%E2%80%93Lehmus_theorem)

EDIT: A large number of proofs, and a much larger number of references to proofs in the literature, can be found at http://www.mathematik.uni-bielefeld.de/~sillke/PUZZLES/steiner-lehmus.

MORE EDIT: There are even proofs on YouTube: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9jViToZi3Kg and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSfMS1z3aic